# PHP print_r $exception->getTrace() Fatal Error (Memory issue)

Tags: php

I am using `print_r($exception->getTrace());` and I get the below error. I want an answer why this error occures when using print_r. When using var_dump it does not occur.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.gettrace.php

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 98570240 bytes) in

```
try {
}
catch (Exception $exception) {
$a = print_r($exception->getTrace()); //memory issue
var_dump($exception->getTrace()); //works fine
}
```

Update:

getTraceAsString() solved this issue in some cases.

Comment: In your php.ini, your current memory limit is 128mb and using print_r with that data is using more than this limit

Comment: Correct but why? That data is coming from php core

Comment: It depends on what your exception contains

Answer (score 1):

if your exception comes from some infinite loop, the trace will be super big and the size can be very large (hundreds of mb).

This error occur because the trace is big, so depending of the type of error and the data it print, if your memory is not set to be big enought, you will have this type of error

EDIT:

The `var_dump` function displays structured information about variables/expressions including its type and value. Arrays are explored recursively with values indented to show structure. It also shows which array values and object properties are references.

The `print_r()` displays information about a variable in a way that's readable by humans. array values will be presented in a format that shows keys and elements. Similar notation is used for objects.

which mean your var_dump does go deeper in each sub-object, will print_r does, recursively.

Comment: i edited my answer taking into account your comment